# How can I calculate the date preceding a given date in unix?

Tags: unix, shell, scripting

I have two variables: X and Y.

The value of X will be a date given in the format *mmddyy*
and I want to calculate the date **preceding** that date **and** have it be returned in in the format *yyyymmdd*.

Let me give you an example. When X="091509" (*mmddyy* format) Y should be "20090914"  (*yyyymmdd* format)

Comment: Shell script or something else?

Comment: shell scripting...............

Comment: i dont want yesterdays date.........i want the date which is one day lessthan the valu of "x"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
~$ date -d "20090101 -1 day"
Wed Dec 31 00:00:00 CET 2008
```

And if you want to retrieve the date in a custom format you just throw in some format strings.

```
~$ date -d "2009-09-15 -1 day" +%Y%m%d
20090914
```

As for your conversion you may use bash substring extraction (assuming you use bash of course). This also assumes that your input is consistent and "safe".

```
X="091509"
Y=`date -d "${X:4:2}${X:0:2}${X:2:2} -1 day" +%Y%m%d`
echo $Y
```

See http://www.walkernews.net/2007/06/03/date-arithmetic-in-linux-shell-scripts/

Comment: This doesn't address the problem of converting your $X to work in this, but yes, let the date command work out which is the day before 030100 (for example).

Comment: @pavium.... right you are. I've added one way of doing such a conversion now. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: This will work on GNU date (e.g. on Linux), but unfortunately `-d` is not portable.

Answer (score 0):

I like Tcl for date arithmetic, even though it's clunky for shell one-liners.  Using Tcl 8.5:

```
x=091509
y=$(printf 'puts [clock format [clock add [clock scan "%s" -format "%%m%%d%%y"] -1 day] -format "%%Y%%m%%d"]' "$x" | tclsh)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the *-d* option doesn't exists on MacOS X or FreeBSD, here is the answer for them

Retrieving a date relative to current time

```
date -v -1d
```

---

For your question in particular, you'll need the *-j* and *-f* flags to use a specific date

```
date -v -1d -j -f %m%d%y 091509 +%Y%m%d
```

Answer (score -1):

date -d "yesterday"