# Get previous day in 'yyyymmdd' format in Bash

Tags: linux, bash

I want to get the previous day in the 'yyyymmdd' format in bash. If today is June 29 2018, I want to get '20180628' as my output.

Comment: Not *really* a duplicate ...

Comment: Porbably but I guess all the keywords in my search were different and hence didn't see this post. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The other answers are overcomplicating it:

```
date -d yesterday '+%Y%m%d'
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for the short answer.

Answer (score 3):

Probably similar to this question: [How can I calculate the date preceding a given date in unix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425295/how-can-i-calculate-the-date-preceding-a-given-date-in-unix)

Following the answer to above referenced question, the solution could be:
`date +"%Y%m%d" -d "-1 day"`

Comment: for correctness, `-d "-1 day"` as an option should appear before the format which is a positional argument, and the quotes should be around the full positional argument: "+%Y%m%d", though quotes are not necessary for this literal arg.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a variable to get the previous day's date like:

```
DATE=`TZ=aaa24 date +%Y%m%d`
echo $DATE
```

Comment: I would actually need this more. Thanks :)